# Multithreading in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface

I want processing data in a thread and, at the same time, maintaining the control on the UI.
In my program, when i click on a "Connect" button, client is connected to a server through a socket, but at the same time i would to start a thread that continuously waits for a message from the server.
My code is approxymately:

```
Thread ListenThread;
SocketClient socket = new SocketClient();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            ListenThread = new Thread(Wait);
            InitializeComponent();
            socket.StartClient(PORT);
        }

private void CONNECT_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            socket.Connect();
            UpdateUI();
            ListenThread.Start();
        }

private void Wait (){
            while (socket.isConnected())
                socket.WaitForSomething();
        }

private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            HandlePressure(e.Key);
        }
```

The problem is that, when I start `ListenThread`, I can't use UI (I have a textbox that collects commands that I must send to the server).
How I can handle this situation?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Thread.
Remember that if you want call method or any controls of window you must use

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=>
{
//Call method or controls of window here
}));
```

Comment: I already use the class `Thread`.
The function `Wait` doesn't control directly UI and I can't use UI.

Comment: Sorry, Could you show me the all code of this file?

Comment: now it works, I don't know where was the mistake. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should collect all information that you need for ListenThread before you call it and then pass it to ListenThread.Start(param1, param2...) or ListenThread.Start(objectWithParameters).

Doing this way you get data on UI thread, which has access to all UI controls and not from another thread that doesn't have access to UI thread.

When you done with calculation on worker thread (ListenThread) you can update UI controls, by [Dispatcher.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Calling Dispatcher delegates call to UI thread, where you can have full access to all controls.

Comment: In  the function called by `ListenThread` (`Wait`) I need informations that I already have (`socket` in this case). I'm not sure understanding what you say.